# How can I remove a single character such as(') on my LargeText View in android

Tags: android, string, escaping, textview

**Xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffb6c1" >
             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/def"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:background="@android:color/white"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                 android:textSize="24dp" />           
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

for Instance i have Sentence in my `File.txt` such that:

sentence=( It's a crazy day).

output in my View LargeText
It(?) a crazy day.

I will like to know a answer for this error I have try to implement `StringBuilder` class but I don't know how to make it work for android.

This is all the changes I have made but still with no Success.

```
package org.health.canser;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
             //setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.breast);
    getFile(breastFile);

}

//my text fiel input section===============================================================================
public String loadTextFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0)
    byteStream.write(bytes, 0, len);
    //return new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
    return new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    }

public void getFile(String fileName)
{


     breast= (View) findViewById(R.id.breastDef);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open(fileName);
    String text = loadTextFile(inputStream);
    Log.i("Msg","msg: " + text);
         ((TextView) breast).setText(text);



    } catch (IOException e) {
    ((TextView) breast).setText("Couldn't load file");
    } finally { 
    if (inputStream != null)
    try {
    inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    ((TextView) breast).setText("Couldn't close file");
    }
    }


}
```

}

OutPut:

01-07 15:03:53.628: I/Msg(24930): Risk factors: Besides being female, increasing age is the most important risk factor for breast cancer. Potentially modifiable risk factors include weight gain after age 18, being overweight or obese (for postmenopausal breast cancer), use of MHT (combined estrogen and progestin hormone therapy), physical inactivity, and alcohol consumption. Medical findings that predict higher risk include high breast tissue density (a mammographic measure of the amount of glandular tissue relative to fatty tissue in the breast), high bone mineral density (women with low density are at increased risk for osteoporosis), and biopsy-confirmed hyperplasia (overgrowth of cells), especially atypical hyperplasia (overgrowth of cells that do not appear normal). High-dose radiation to the chest for cancer treatment also increases risk. Reproductive factors that increase risk include a long menstrual history (menstrual periods that start early and/or end later in life), recent use of oral contraceptives, never having children, and having **one?s** first child after age 30.

Comment: Please show us the code where you set the text.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, your problem is your ' in sentence is being replaced by (?) , Am I correct?

Comment: When you read the text from the file in your application, are you using the same character encoding as the file itself is using?

Comment: Also, it's useful to know if that file.txt is produced by you or if you can modify it's contents prior to be read

Comment: @changdeo yea you got the right point.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer maybe, but it should help alot:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String czech = "Český";
        String japanese = "日本語";

        System.out.println("UTF-8 czech: " + new String(czech.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        System.out.println("UTF-8 japanese: " + new String(japanese.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        System.out.println("ISO-8859-1 czech: " + new String(czech.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
        System.out.println("ISO-8859-1 japanese: " + new String(japanese.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
    }

}
```

UTF-8 czech: Český
 UTF-8 japanese: 日本語
 ISO-8859-1 czech: ?esk�
 ISO-8859-1 japanese: ???

ISO-8859-1 is the standard encode for android. So that is why you probably get the "?" character, instead of the proper character.

You need to change this to UTF-8.
I think you can figure out how if you look at the example above.